# Library or app to dynamically compare two dbs and suggest transform scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server

I did a search online and was not able to find any tool or app that were designed to do this. I am looking for a set of C# class libraries you can link or reference into your code, or external command-line application that would allow me to dynamically compare two database schemas and generate scripts for transforming one database into the other, without loosing any data in a relatively speedy fashion. All tools I have seen so far, works in a static manner, i.e. you are comparing one db to the next to generate change scripts on your own local system. I am planning to include this in an installer, so it will run on a remote system therefore making it critical that it is possible to automate the process. Also licensing should be somewhat successible to that fact, i.e. a small fee per install is acceptable, or a larger one time fee and no inclusion fee.

Comment: I guess you didn't search too thoroughly. Red-Gate has command line options as do [several alternatives](http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/). We can't help with licensing questions in the slightest, though; once you find a product that does what you need, you'll have to contact them directly to find out about redistribution etc.

Comment: As I wrote below, I already looked into Redgate, however from their description, it is not clear whether they allow you to link their tools into your own applications. They mention  SQL Automation Pack, however it sound like something you can run on a build server, not distribute with your software.

Comment: We have created our company's deployment application using the Redgate and as jeffo said, we used it's command line to compare the database schema between builds/labels. And yes, you need to purchase the redgate license for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redgate can do that. Try their site http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: Yes, I looked into RedGate, however looking through their description on their site, it appears to be a static tool you run locally, not one you can link into your own applications or distribute with your installer, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There is a command line you can run, so yes your installer could certainly run it.  You would have to check with red gate for licensing though.

Comment: We have created our company's deployment application using the Redgate and as jeffo said, we used it's command line to compare the database schema between builds/labels. And yes, you need to purchase the redgate license for it.